# Apple Certificate revoke

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, code-signing-certificate

I've 2 target one is Runner and another is OneSignalNotification. If I revoke OneSignal the Runner asks for revoke certificate If I revoke Runner Onesignal asks for revoke

[image: Runner and OneSignalNotification are Target At a time only one works]

How can I use same certificate in every single app and every target.

***This issues starts when I clean up my unused certificates and I delete a working certificate unfortunately***

Comment: Are you by any chance trying to use the same bundle ID on both targets?

Answer (score 1):

To change the certificate, you must change the `team` and the `bundle identifier`. Changing one at a time will cause problems. Also, in Xcode press `Command+,` and go to accounts. Make sure that all of your account information is correct.